# What are the difference between byte code and bit code

Tags: java, gcc, compiler-construction, llvm, bytecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between LLVM and java bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454720/what-are-the-differences-between-llvm-and-java-bytecode)

For example, in LLVM, it said..

```
What is commonly known as the LLVM bitcode file format 
(also, sometimes anachronistically known as bytecode) is actually two things: 
a bitstream container format and an encoding of LLVM IR into the container 
format.
```

I only know Java Bytecode which is platform independent which can be run by the JVM

But for the LLVM bit code, are there more concrete examples?

Comment: Asking the difference between bytecode and bitcode is ***NOT*** the same as asking the difference between Java bytecode and LLVM bytecode, which should be obvious to anyone who actually takes the time to read the questions and think about them.  The fact that the facts of the answer have some overlap is irrelevant.  The questions are very different.

Answer (score 3):

From the [LLVM mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-September/035076.html):

> The format is literally a bitstream, not a bytestream.  See this
>   document for more details: http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html