# cc1.exe fail to initialize modified dragonegg.dll

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, llvm

I want to generate LLVM bitcode rather than LLVM IR, from C and C++ source.
Original version of dragonegg works correctly.
Since it doesn't have a function to emit LLVM bitcode, I tried to add that, but it doesn't work.
What's wrong with my modification?

> gcc -fplugin=dragonegg.dll -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-llvm -I ..\include -c test.c
>
> cc1.exe: error: fail to initialize plugin dragonegg.dll

I posted my patch to gist.
https://gist.github.com/vroad/1f2dcd2c37e03005a349

I compiled latest LLVM and dragonegg with plugin-enabled gcc for Windows.

SourceForge.net: MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28248366

Comment: Oh-huh. LLVM... *on Windows...* I couldn't compile it neither on Linux nor on OS X... You're either very brave or very clever or both.

Comment: I think "LLVM bitcode" is correct expression. This term is used in documents and code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469301/what-are-the-difference-between-byte-code-and-bit-code

Comment: @H2CO3 You can compile LLVM using CMake on any platforms, can't you? Loadable module seems unsupported on Windows, though.

Comment: @H2CO3 my build crashed a few hours ago after 34 hours of compiling.. (error: memory exhausted)